# how can i add SLF4J to my jbpm java project? i dont have pom.xml in my project

Tags: java, slf4j, jbpm

I am creating a new jbpm java project and following this tutorial:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jbpm5/jbpm5_hello_world.htm

but every time i run the hello world project, this error appears:

> ```
> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
> SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
> WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
> WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter (file:/C:/Users/Sir.%20Berry/Downloads/droolsjbpm-integration-distribution-6.5.0.Final/xstream.jar) to field java.util.TreeMap.comparator
> WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter
> WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
> WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at com.sample.ProcessTest.main(ProcessTest.java:20)
> ```

Concerning the slf4j, I did my research and I guess I should import it somewhere but not sure where exactly,

I am new to this jbpm thing,
 any help?

Comment: The class has to be available on the [classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

Comment: hey thanks for your reply but i tried the command from the site you mentioned and nothing happened.. i typed this : C:> sdkTool -classpath classpath1;classpath2...

in my cmd and replaced the class paths with my class path, in my case (C:\Users\Sir. Berry\Desktop\java files\slf4j-nop.jar) but the error still appears